# CDF for exponential family

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, distribution-theory

Might be a stupid question though...

we know for Exponential Family, we have the density is
$$f(x|\theta)=h(x)\exp[\eta(\theta)\cdot T(x)-A(\theta)]$$
Is there a general form for the CDF function? I know if we specify a member from the exponential family, like normal, exponential, etc, the question would be simple. But is there a general form of the CDF?

Thanks~

Comment: I think this will be limited by the close form of the solution - for example the CDF of the gaussian/normal is not closed form and is instead defined in terms of the `erf`-whilst the exponential is defined clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Well, a general form is straight yielded by the expression of $f(x|\theta)$. Nothing more than that though, as there are cases where you can't have a CDF in terms of a closed form, for example the gaussian or the normal distribution, which yield non-common functions).

For continuous distributions belonging to the Exponential Family (for a random sample-distribution defined over the space $x \in \mathcal{X}$):

$$F_x(x|\theta) = \int_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f(x|\theta)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f(x|\theta)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \bigg\{h(x)\exp[\eta(\theta)\cdot T(x)-A(\theta)]\bigg\}\mathrm{d}x $$

For discrete distributions belonging to the Exponential Family (for a random sample $X_1, \dots, X_n$) :

$$F_x(x|\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i|\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n \bigg\{h(x_i)\exp[\eta(\theta)\cdot T(x_i)-A(\theta)]\bigg\}$$